# How do I search for higlighted text by color in MS Word?

Tags: search, microsoft-word-2007

In MS word, I have many differenet highlighted colors of text.  How can I search for them by color in MS Word 2007?

Comment: This appears to be impossible :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of Word, you can search through the raw XML of the document.

1. Save and close the document in Word.
2. Unzip the Word document (you can use 7-Zip).  Modern .docx documents are ZIP files with XML files inside.
3. Find the “document.xml” file in the “word” folder.
4. Search for `<w:highlight w:val="red"/>` and similar tags.

This is a very cumbersome answer.

Comment: Also, if you have a sufficiently current version of Windows, you can make a copy of the ``.docx`` file, rename it to a ``.zip`` extension,  and open it with Windows Explorer.

Comment: At the same time, despite being cumbersome, it's the only legit answer.

Answer (score 1):

### HOME, EDITING, FIND

**For font colour**

Find what: *, Use wildcards, Format, Font, (choose Font color).

Note, this finds one character at a time (and one colour at a time).

---

**For highlighting** (*I'm not sure which you mean*)

Find what: *, Use wildcards, select `*`, Format, Highlight.

Note, this finds one character at a time but any highlighting colour at the same pass.

Comment: A pretty good answer to a poorly worded question. One could interpret the question as asking about _highlighted **colors of text**_ or about _**highlighted** colors of **text**_.  As an add-on, you can search for **blocks** of font colours (multiple characters, but still one colour at a time) and **blocks** of highlighted text (any colour in one pass) by putting nothing in the _Find what:_ box and leaving the _Use wildcards_ box unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is far outdated as a reply, but since more users could have a similar problem, this is my partial solution.

In versions of MS Word that use the Ribbon, click on the drop-down menu of the Find icon to choose the Advanced Find.
In the new window locate the "More>>" button and at the bottom, there is a label "Find" with an option button Format. Click on it and chose "Highlight" (though I have yet to find how to set the color in this short time I had to reply).

---

This edited answer is a more suitable workaround for something that apparently no one could answer so far, so I decided to keep the original answer (before the line above) as a reply to a question that fits **most** users that end up on this page (no point complicating what doesn't need to be complicated), and elaborate on a new one.

Taking into account on what is stated in MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/find-object-word) one can retrieve the following information:

The *Find.Execute* method does not have any regards to highlight, as in itself highlight is not a format, as the name indicates, it's just a highlight.

The *Find.Highlight* property only admits the normal Boolean (`True`, `False`) and `wdUndefined` (ignoring highlights), and as such doesn’t allow specifying a color.

The *Find.HitHighLight* method applies to Outlook objects but can be used in Word to find and remove highlight (but again not to specify a specific color among several colors), for example,
`ActiveDocument.Content.Find.HitHighlight FindText:="text to find"`

With the previous statements one can indeed find it impossible (or at least to me) to find **different** colors without a complex macro that compares each character to the default color of highlight (which I'm sure not going to make...) or editing the file code (which is a good solution, in my view, so kudos for the user that posted it, but as the user stated a cumbersome answer to most users of Word). In my opinion, there's a more suitable and easy **workaround** using the far easier to use *Advanced Find* with the ***Style*** option.
For that you have to use a Style with *Shading* instead of the highlight (or combining both).

So using my previous instructions, besides the *Highlight* option,
 you can also use the *Style* option to search for a previous added style(s) with the same color(s) you want to find, or if you prefer a shading color and a highlight of the word for a more complete and narrowed search.

Comment: Next time you answer a six-year-old question, please take the extra six minutes to see whether your answer *really* answers the question. This can be used to search for ***all*** highlighted text. If it can be used to search only for blue-highlighted text, for example, nobody has been able to figure out how. If you do know how to do this, please explain how. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete. Otherwise, this does not answer the question.

Comment: I did stated that it does not answer the question exactly but it does answer most of the question and why most users end up in this page, me included. As it is a viable workaround, not in the highlight itself, but the STYLE option, which i'm editing right after. At least my comment was more useful than your, as the only time you took to analyse my answer was to simply discard it an try to insult me...

Comment: An excellent answer. While Style is not something most users use, with a little setup, it has great potential to do things that could fit a wide range of use-cases. Also, regarding the _Find.HitHighLight_ method, it may be worth mentioning that the _FindText_ parameter, although required, can be set to the empty string `""` to search only using formatting. Also, I haven't experimented yet, but the parameters HighlightColor and FontColor both appear to take a specific color. Thanks for pointing out those members of _Find_.

Answer (score 0):

Because I got this outdated question on the first page, I have to write how it works now as a state-of-art of March 2024.
My case is to search the different sections of work colored according to my own legend. So in a long paper, it is a challenge to overview and edit.

This way works with desktop MS Word 365. Didn't test it with the online version.

To search Highlights or Colored text you should to do:

1. Open the Find dialogue (ctrl+f).
2. Bottom left button "More" to open advanced settings.
3. a. To search Highlights - press bottom left Format and select Highlight to enable it. Do the same to disable it.

**!!! Importan**t - the settings of a search are under the text field "Find what" and named "Format". Control the state of the request there.

3. b. Set the "font color" field to search. It works well but single choice only.
   [image]

Use any combination as you need to get it done :)